# Error when setting an array index with an object in vbscript?

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I'm trying to create an array of objects in vbscript, where each object has a string and a number as properties. The string is coming from a different array, and the number is incremented in the loop.

---

Here's the error occurring, on the line `newValues(i) = (New Pet)(values(i), number)`:

[image]

---

...and here's my code:

```
Class Pet
    Public objectName
    Public objectNumber

    ' constructor here:
    Public Default Function Init(name, number)
        objectName = name
        objectNumber = number

        Set Init = Me
    End Function
End Class

values = Array(_
    "Cat",_
    "Dog",_
    "Bird"_
)

number = 3
ReDim newValues(uBound(values))

For i = 0 to uBound(values)
    newValues(i) = (New Pet)(values(i), number)
    number = number + 1
Next
```

Comment: Use `Set` when assigning objects. `Set newValues(i) = (New Pet)(values(i), number)`

Comment: Thanks @Bond, post this as an answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Set` when assigning objects.

```
Set newValues(i) = (New Pet)(values(i), number)
```